# Preheat S3 partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In this documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-503-within-request-rate-prefix/): amazon states

> Amazon S3 supports a request rate of 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE and 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix in a bucket. The resources for this request rate aren't automatically assigned when a prefix is created.

In my application, I am creating a large number of prefixes at roughly the same time, and starting to query them.  It seems like if you don't heed S3's error 503 "SlowDown", you eventually start getting the more stern error 403 "Access Denied".  However, because my application is distributed, it is difficult for me to do exponential backoff when receiving error 503 SlowDown, since one node can get this "warning" and properly throttle itself while another gets 403, which I don't think I should retry.  My application is fairly complex and changing it to throttle itself only right after creating the partitions would be a pain, so the simplest solution for me (if its possible) would be:

Is there a way to simply ask S3 if a newly created prefix is its own shard yet?

I assume the answer is no, but it would save me some headache if it was actually yes...

If not, does anybody have any idea how long, or how many requests, does it typically take to provision new partitions behind the scenes?

Comment: You can open support tickets to let the AWS support check and provision extra partitions for you.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little less manual (this process happens when a customer requests resources from us)

Comment: There is no public API way to do this AFAIK.

Comment: Are you running into actual problems, or are you just preparing for potential issues?

Comment: I was running into problems when creating customer resources with large numbers of prefixes at the same time.  I fixed the problems by creating the resources in waves (once all the partitions are spun up in the background everything runs smoothly, so it seems I just need to be careful during creation).